# Click on an LI and send that value to an input as the value with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, html-lists, attr

I am trying to click on an LI, and have the value of that li sent to a search box input as the value to search for.

I can strip the class from the LI but do not know how to strip out the LI itself. I am probably going at this completely wrong.

```
$(function(){
//var art = $('li.inliner').val();
$('li.inliner').on('click',function(){// select the artist from the ul
$( this ).clone() //copy it
.removeClass("inliner") //remove the inliner class
//remove the li from the clone??
.appendTo( "input(value)?? ); //this needs to be inserted into the search input as the value
  });
})
```

Currently I can send the clicked LI to a div with the class removed, but its still an LI. I also dont know how to make it the input value. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you give a before and after HTML example?  Like what the HTML looks like to start with, and what it should look like after a `li.inliner` is clicked?

Comment: Here is the page. Click on one of the artists names and that name will appear to your left. What I want to do is put it in the search box at the bottom of the page http://chill.shivabeach.com/display/artists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I get it the right way you could try something like

```
$(function(){
//WHEN YOU CLICK THE ELEMENT..
$('li.inliner').on('click',function(){
//GET THE TEXT INSIDE THAT SPECIFIC LI
var content= $(this).text();
//PLACE THE TEXT INSIDE THE INPUT FIELD, YOU CAN CHANGE YOUR SELECTOR TO TARGET THE RIGHT INPUT
$('input[name='MySearchBox']').val(content);
//HERE YOU CAN DO SOMETHING ELSE LIKE SIBMITING THE FORM, OR CLICK A BUTTON.. OR SOMETHING ELSE
  });
});
```

I hope this is what you need.  I made a little example using a different selector for the input. hope this works for you.

http://jsfiddle.net/kbFUu/1/

Comment: I took the body out of the on(body, click) and it worked perfectly! TY!

Comment: The .on() method is reserve for events not elements or selectors.

Comment: Are you saying just use .click()?

Comment: I'm saying @Leo is using improper syntax. The .on() method is used as $('.my-selector').on('event', someFunction);. You can add an option selector *after* the event type to prevent bubbling (see more about bubbling here - http://api.jquery.com/on/), but its not really necessary in this case with way the element is being targeted. Hope that helps.

Comment: @Swordfish0321 My mistake he he... I wasn't really thinking about it . $('body').on('click', 'li.inliner'.... was what I was thinking about XD.   Thx for the comment.

Answer (score 2):

You want to add something like this to your code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // use event delegation to listen for '.inliner' clicks
    $('ul.liner').on('click', '.inliner', function(){
        // when an element is clicked, update the search box
        $('#art').attr('value', $(this).text())
    })
});
```

Comment: I think this would work too. I selected Leos answer before I seen  yours. Thanks Jeremy

Comment: @Brad Much better option to the OPs problem.

Comment: what exactly does not work? I have tried this code on your site and it worked fine. Note: all this does is copy the value from the LI over to the search box. It doesn't clone the LI into the left hand column.

Comment: It didnt have any response. I clicked it and nothing happened.

Comment: Sounds good to me. As long as it is working for you now then that is great!